# Is there a way to go back a few seconds in a movie on iTunes on a Mac?

Tags: itunes, movie

Such as going back 5 or 10 seconds. This is a function I needed most but don't find on iTunes.

P.S. the <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Opt</kbd> Left arrow doesn't work by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Cmd+Option+Left Arrow** to skip backwards five seconds.

Use **Cmd+Option+Right Arrow** to skip forward five seconds.

Hold the keys down and you'll keep skipping backwards or forwards with momentary pauses so you can keep up.

Comment: I Googled and got this result too but it didn't work

Comment: This only works for me in music. iTunes 12.8.

Comment: Is there a way to remap this to a different shortcut? I cannot find it in the menus in music 1.2.2.40